# Pika SelectConnection acknowledge message by long running tasks

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have this queue system where I use pika's SelectConnection to consume a Rabbitmq queue , but my tasks can processed for a long time and in this time Rabbitmq can close connection and my task requeue to Rabbitmq because I can`t acknowledge message. To exclude requeue I transferred the code with acknowledge message before processing the message but the result did not see. I get the code from this example [from here](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html)

And change processing code to this:

```
def start_processing(self):
    self._channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    self._channel.add_on_cancel_callback(self.on_consumer_cancelled)
    self._consumer_tag = self._channel.basic_consume(self.process_message,
                  self._queue,
                  no_ack=False,
                  exclusive=False)


def process_message(self, unused_channel, basic_deliver, properties, body):
    self._channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=basic_deliver.delivery_tag)
    self.handle_message(body)
```

And acknowledge message don't work before the message did not processed

Comment: First, try your code without `self.handle_message` - does it work then?

Comment: Yes, it work without `self.handle_message`

Comment: You must run `self.process` in such a way as to not block `SelectConnection`. This is a general Python programming question and not specific to Pika.